# Clipping Multiple Polygons in Single Layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

I have about 10K polygons for a single layer. Many of these polygons are overlapping. I would like to clip the polygons and either have the overlap merge to one of the polygons or even split in the middle if possible.

There is an example below:

**Overlap**

[image]

**Clipped and merged**

[image]

I've used the Clipper Plugin tool which works great, but is very manual, and would like to see if anyone has found a batch process?